# The type 'System.Drawing.Graphics' has no constructors defined

Tags: c#, graphics, paint

```
Graphics g = new Graphics();
```

I was trying to create a graphics object for painting on Windows From Application but for some reason, the Graphics() class doesn't have a constructor. How do I create a new object for g. then?

Comment: you must load graphics from something, else don't initialize the instance

Comment: @Sam What do you mean by load it? I already have using System.Drawing;

Comment: The draw function will pass it to you as a param usually.

Comment: @Mike using Graphics static methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the documentation for the class at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> You can obtain a Graphics object by calling the Control.CreateGraphics method on an object that inherits from System.Windows.Forms.Control, or by handling a control's Control.Paint event and accessing the Graphics property of the System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs class. You can also create a Graphics object from an image by using the FromImage method. For more information about creating a Graphics object, see How to: Create Graphics Objects for Drawing.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from the excellent answer by xbonez...

CreateGraphics() is almost never the correct approach.

If you use the Paint() event, there is a Graphics supplied for you via the arguments usually in the form of `e.Graphics`.

If you have an Image or Bitmap, you can use Graphics.FromImage() to obtain a Graphics to draw onto the image.

There are examples of these on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y289054%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page.

Comment: Important note, if you create a Graphics from one of the methods other than the Paint event ***be sure*** you dispose of the graphics object (just make sure to put it in a using statement), you may get `OutOfMemoryException`s when you run out of GDI+ resources if you don't.